# By Pressing tabs to add Rows Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

[image]How to add rows to table by pressing tab in php.

Hi, I want to add rows to table by pressing tabs in php, For 1s row its working fine. but for dynamic rows its not working correctly.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="default" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('inventory_c/add_purchase/'.$this->session->userdata('cus_id'));?>">

                <div  style="width:100%; align:left; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <!--table class="table table-bordered"-->
                     <table class="table table-striped table-hover metable table-bordered" id="editable-sample">
                        <tr>
                            <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
                            <th>S.No</th>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>

                            <th >Vat %</th>
                            <th >Rate</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <!--th>Action</th-->
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
                            <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text'    id='itemname_1' name='itemname[]' autofocus/>

                            </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='quantity_no_1' name='quantity_no[]'/>
                            <input type='hidden' name='customer_id_1' id='customer_id_1' value='<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cus_id') ?>' class='form-control' />
                            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='supplier_id_1' name='supplier_id[]' />
                            <input type="hidden"  id="dummy_itemnum" />
                            <input type="hidden"  id="dummy_itemname" />
                            </td>


                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled  maxlength="200" id='vat_no_1' name='vat_no[]' value=""/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled  maxlength="200" id='rate_no_1' name='rate_no[]'/> </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled id='total_no_1' name='total_no[]'/> </td>
                            <!--td id="hideAddRow">
                            <div id="hideAddRow">
                            <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addRow' id='addRow'>+ Add More</button>
                            </div>
                            </td-->
                            </tr>

                    </table>

                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ Add More</button>

                    <section class="panel">
                        <input type="submit" class="finish btn btn-primary" value="Finish" name="submit" id="submit">
                    </section>

            </form>
```

my script code:

```
   $('#quantity_no_1').bind("keydown", function(event) {

   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
   if (keycode == 9) { 


      count=$('table tr').length;

      var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
data +="<td><input class='form-control' type='text' autofocus id='itemname_"+i+"' name='itemname[]'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='quantity_no_"+i+"' name='quantity_no[]'/><input type='hidden' name='customer_id' id='customer_id' value='<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cus_id') ?>' class='form-control' /><input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='supplier_id"+i+"' name='supplier_id' /><input  class='form-control' type='hidden'  id='dummy_itemnum_"+i+"' name='dummy_itemnum[]' /><input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='dummy_itemname_"+i+"' name='dummy_itemname[]' />  </td><td><input class='form-control' disabled type='text' id='vat_no_"+i+"' name='vat_no[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' disabled id='rate_no_"+i+"' name='rate_no[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' disabled type='text' id='total_no_"+i+"' name='total_no[]'/></td></tr>";

$('table').append(data);
row = i;

$('#itemname_'+i).autocomplete({

source: function( request, response ) {

    $.ajax({

                //type: "POST",
                url: "product_autocomplete",
                dataType: "json",
                //cache: false,
                method: 'post',
                //data: 'name_startsWith='+request.term+'&type='+'country_table'+'&row_num='+row,
                data: {
                   name_startsWith: request.term,
                   type: 'country_table',
                   row_num : row
                },

             success: function( data ) 
               {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item )
                  {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                              }
                  }));
               }


               }); 

},
autoFocus: true,            
minLength: 0,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");                 
    //$('#quantity_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
    var al = $('#vat_no_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
    //alert(al);
    $('#rate_no_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
    $('#supplier_id'+id[1]).val(names[4]);
}   
});


    $('#quantity_no_'+i).change(function(){

var icon = $('#itemname_'+id[1]).val();
var icon1 = icon.split('-');
 $('#dummy_itemnum_'+id[1]).val(icon1[0]);
  $('#dummy_itemname_'+id[1]).val(icon1[1]);
var itemnum = $('#dummy_itemnum_'+id[1]).val();
var itemname = $('#dummy_itemname_'+id[1]).val();
var quantity = $('#quantity_no_'+id[1]).val(); 
var rate_no = $('#rate_no_'+id[1]).val();
var vat_no = $('#vat_no_'+id[1]).val();
var sales = parseInt(rate_no*quantity);
$('#total_no_'+id[1]).val(sales);
var t1 = $('#total_no_1').val();
//alert(t1);
var t2 = $('#total_no_'+id[1]).val();
var a = parseInt(t1);
var b = parseInt(t2);
var c  = a+b; 

$('#total_amt').val(c);

var t3 = parseFloat(t1+t2);

var supplier_id = $('#supplier_id'+id[1]).val();
var customer_id = $('#customer_id').val();

$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "add_temp_purchase",
                cache: false,
                data: 'itemnum='+itemnum+'&itemname='+itemname+'&costprice='+rate_no+'&quantity='+quantity+'&customer_id='+customer_id+'&sales='+sales+'&supplier_id='+supplier_id,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(returnhtml) {

                }

                });

});


i++;


}
  [enter image description here][1]});
```

Comment: It is better to use `keyup` event

Comment: ya i was tried that event also, its only applicable for adding one rows..  not for dynamic rows..

Comment: As per my view you need to send one ajax for append new row below last row, So you can easily change in future and also can manage. Where you want to add `i` for make unique id there you should use `.(class)` as selector, I am also working same your task

Comment: where i want to set the unique id

Comment: yes i have tried that (class as separator) but still not getting.. below is my code..          $('.qty_no').on("keyup", function() {  });                                     <input class="qty_no" type='text' id='quantity_no_1' name='quantity_no[]'/>

Comment: only applicable for single items not for dynamic

Comment: where i want to send ajax code can u pls provide me what i want to declare in this ajax code. please do my needs @ Thanks